# Redirect Window from iFrame

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe

I was hoping somebody could please assist on a problem I am currently having. I have an `IFrame` named **IFrame1** implemented on a client website. On the client website they have certain information of the user in the `QueryString` for instance `clientwebsite.com/login.aspx?UserID=xxxx&UserName=xxxx`.

Using `MVC` what would be the best way of retrieving the entire querystring while I only have an `IFrame` on the website?

I tried using `JavaScript` to retrieve the `window.location` but this only displays the URL where my `IFrame` is deployed (MyServer.com) and not where it has been implemented(clientwebsite.com). I also tried using C# [HttpRequest.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx). This also just displays the URL where my solution was deployed and not the client website URL.

If anybody has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***

I tried using the `window.parent.location` as many suggest. I wrote a small webpage where I just pull the code and display it as follows :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("window.location.href : " + window.location.href + "<br />");
    document.write("window.parent.location : " + window.parent.location + "<br />");
    document.write("document.referrer : " + document.referrer + "<br />");
</script>
```

When I run this page I get the result as follows :

```
window.location.href http://mywebsite.com/test
window.parent.location http://mywebsite.com/test
document.referrer
```

Which is fine but when I view this through the clientwebsite it onlyu displays the href value but neither the window.parent.location label or the value. Can this be caused due to permissions?

Comment: Try `document.referrer` to get the parent's URL

Comment: try using  `window.parent.location` to get the parent's url

Answer (score 0):

You should try using :

```
var parentUrl = window.parent.location;
```

window.parent will get you inside the parent window and then you can do anything with the parent window.

Hi Ruben,

I believe you need to add window.parent.location.search . You can do something like this for query string. This answer was provided by Marwan:

```
function getQueryString() {
            var queryStringKeyValue = window.parent.location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
            var qsJsonObject = {};
            if (queryStringKeyValue != '') {
                for (i = 0; i < queryStringKeyValue.length; i++) {
                    qsJsonObject[queryStringKeyValue[i].split('=')[0]] = queryStringKeyValue[i].split('=')[1];
                }
            }
            return qsJsonObject;
        }
```

Just call it from the child window like this and act with the query string as an object.

For example if you have the query string ?name=stack and you want to get it, try:

```
getQueryString().name
```

This will return stack.

Comment: I added this to my edit part. Please look at what happened and if you can think of why this is happening.

Comment: Hi @RubenRedman, I have edited above answer. Have look. This should be good now. All the above code should be in iframe.